# What parts make up this mini-figure?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

[image: Knight figure]

I need a little help in identifying the parts on this figure.

Here is what I need help with:

- The Hat/plume
- The Torso
- The Cape (though it looks like it might be made of two capes instead of one).
- The part that is holding the sword.

Hope the group can give me some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pirate hat: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2528#T=C

Plume: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4502c#T=C

Torso: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0665c01#T=C&C=11

Capes (appear to be two standard capes): https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=522#T=C

Scabbard: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=95348#T=C